# Accessibility Service - Hardware KeyPress

Tags: accessibility, accessibilityservice

Is it possible to send past command so that it pastes text into currently focused edit text, I am using RFID reader Hardware. Scenario:

1. Background service listening for notification (done)
2. When notification is received text needs to be copied to clipboard (done)
3. Paste text to any currently focused field (done)
4. On Hardware RFID reader button trigger, I am getting source as null

   @Override
   public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
       Log.e("-onAccessibilityEvent-", "----------");

   ```
   AccessibilityNodeInfo source2 = event.getSource();
   if (source2 == null) {
       return;
   }

   //    if (source2 != null && event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED) {

       ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
       ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", r);
       clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
       source2.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_PASTE);
   }
   ```

   }

I know how to copy text with ClipboardManager.

Comment: What language is this in? Java?

Comment: Yes, Java, Normal Events are working fine, the problem is with hardware key press

Comment: My requirement is read RFID then print value to text box where cursor focusing, need to work in any app

Comment: It isn't apparently clear what you believe your issue is. What is the specific ask here? Why is even.getSource() always null? Or just the generic ask... is this possible? The answer is "Yes". Though I doubt that will help you. Assuming that the core issue is that event.getSource() is always null, you have not provided near enough information to begin answering that question. Namely, ServiceConfig XML. Beyond that, as this question is asked, it is far too broad for Stack Overflow. The answer would be an entire repository, given all of the potential issues. Ask questions in consumable chunks!

Comment: Hi Chris, Thank You. If I use hardware key press from scanning device  if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (keyCode == KeyCode.ALR_H450.SCAN) {...
In this case i am getting event.getSOurce() as null
Please find the link in https://github.com/georgeyjohn/RFID/